# Path with loop in it

Tags: neo4j

How big are orders of returning customers compared to their first order at a store? This is the best I have so far. Email represents the ID of a shopper.

```
match (e:Email)--(o:Order)--(s:Shop {domain:"shop"})--(p:Order)--(e) 
where o.created_at<p.created_at 
return avg(log(toFloat(p.total_price_usd)/toFloat(o.total_order_price)));
```

Is there a smart way to get this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query shows one way to get the ratio of reorder totals to initial order totals. It first calculates the average ratio per email node, and then it calculates the average of those averages.

```
MATCH (e:Email)--(o:Order)--(s:Shop {domain:"shop"})
WITH e, o
ORDER BY o.created_at
WITH e, COLLECT(o.total_price_usd) AS totals, COUNT(o) AS nOrders
WHERE nOrders >= 2
WITH e, apoc.coll.sum(TAIL(totals)) / (nOrders-1) / HEAD(totals) AS ratio
RETURN AVG(ratio) AS result;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause sorts the orders per email node by creation time, to identify the initial one. The `WHERE` clause drops email nodes that only have 1 order. The APOC function [apoc.coll.sum](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) is a convenient way to calculate the sum of a collection.